# wpf Datatrigger - prevent from triggering OnLoad

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two animations triggered by true/false code-behind variable.
If the variable is true - one of the animations starts, if false the other starts.

But how to achieve no animation on load of the app?

Comment: I've just came up with idea, that I will create two vars - each trigger bound to one of them. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you refer to you previous question then try removing `From` values from your animations and let it animate from current value. This way on start it won't animate from default `Opacity` of 1

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a bool?, meaning a nullable boolean, so you have three states (null, true, false) or you could write a DependencyProperty which can have an initial Value of UnsetValue (DependencyProperty.UnsetValue).